# Problem with string input validation (C++)

Tags: c++, string, validation

I ran into a problem while trying to validate my user input. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  string choice;


  cout << "Please type something: ";
  cin >> choice;
  cin.ignore();

  while (choice != "1" && choice != "2" && choice != "3" && choice != "4" && choice != "5")
  {
    cout << "Incorrect choice! Please input a valid number: >_";
    cin >> choice;
    cin.ignore();
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

When I input "wronginput", that input fell in the while loop and displayed

> Incorrect choice! Please input a valid number: >_

Which is good. However, when I try "wrong input", I get a "weird" version of it:

> Incorrect choice! Please input a valid number: >_ Incorrect choice! Please input a valid number: >_

My guess is that the space in between is the culprit. Is there any way for me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: `cin` reads one word at a time, separated by whitespace.  When you pass multiple words, they get queued up and processed in order.

Comment: use `getline` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `std::cin >> choice` is a formatted input that will read everything *to the next whitespace*.

When you type in "wronginput", it reads it all, but if you type in "wrong input", only the "wrong" part will be read. Your `while` loop will fire, perform `std::cin >> choice` inside its body once again and that will read "input".

This behaviour causes your program to output the message twice in a row.

How to fix it? Instead of reading a single *token*, up to the next whitespace, consider reading *an entire line*.

---

How to achieve that? Simply instead of using

```
std::cin >> choice;
```

use a [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function:

```
std::getline(std::cin, choice);
```

both outside and inside your `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Also, I'll get rid of 'cin.ignore()' since they cause unnecessary pauses.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter "wrong input" for input, the line

```
cin >> choice;
```

reads and stores "wrong" in `choice`.

The line

```
cin.ignore();
```

ignores only one character. Hence, you stull have "input" and the subsequent newline character in the stream. Next time you read into `choice`, you get "input" in `choice`.

That explains the behavior of your program.

In order to fix it, make sure to ignore the rest of the line instead of just one character. Use

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.